# How to fix "Too many positional arguments: 1 expected, but 3 found." issue in flutter

Tags: flutter, provider

I'm new to flutter.
I need to get product information through a form using flutter provider.
I can get one object(like String name value only). But when I add multiple parameters, it shows the following error.

> Too many positional arguments: 1 expected, but 3 found.

This is the code I wrote.

**Model class**

```
class Item {
  String itemName;
  String description;
  double itemPrice;
  Item(this.itemName, this.description, this.itemPrice);
}
```

**ChangeNotifier class**

```
class ItemAddNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Item> itemList = [];
  addItem(String itemName, String description, double itemPrice) {
    Item item = Item(itemName, description, itemPrice);
    itemList.add(item);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**Add items**

```
class AddItems extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController _itemNameTextEditing = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _itemDescriptionTextEditing =
      TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _itemPriceTextEditing = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Kavishka'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: _itemNameTextEditing,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                hintText: 'Item Name',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: _itemDescriptionTextEditing,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                hintText: 'Item Description',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: _itemPriceTextEditing,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                hintText: 'Item Price',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('ADD ITEM'),
              onPressed: () async {
                if (_itemNameTextEditing.text.isEmpty) {
                  return;
                }
                await Provider.of<ItemAddNotifier>(context, listen: false)
                    .addItem(
                        _itemNameTextEditing.text,
                        _itemDescriptionTextEditing.text,
                        _itemPriceTextEditing.text);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Home Screen**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Kavishka'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    fullscreenDialog: true,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return AddItems();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.add))
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Consumer<ItemAddNotifier>(builder: (context, itemAddNotifier, _) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: itemAddNotifier.itemList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            itemAddNotifier.itemList[index].itemName,
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Main**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) {
        return ItemAddNotifier();
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: HomeScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It shows the error in `Item item = Item(itemName, description, itemPrice);` line.
If someone can help me to fix this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: The above code works for me. No errors whatsoever. However, try making your contstructor with named parameters `Item({required this.itemName,required this.description, required this.itemPrice});`

Comment: @esentis Thank you for your reply. The above code doesn't work for me. It underline changeNotifier class description as red. are there any mistakes in my code?

Comment: Nope there isn't any problem. Have you imported material ? `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`

Comment: @esentis Yeah I have. I will update with my all code. Can you check it if there is issue with another dart file please?

Comment: @esentis I changed it with my all files. Can you check it please whether there is an issue with another dart file?

Comment: The only error I found is at your add `AddItems` class where the `_itemPriceTextEditing.text` is a `String` while it waits for a `double`, try `double.tryParse(_itemPriceTextEditing.text)`. Other than that, no errors.

Comment: @esentis I have already fixed it, but issue is same.

Comment: Try tweaking the `Item` constructor as per my first comment.

Comment: Please add the log of the error you are getting, to know exactly where and why the problem is occurring.